# gcc(v4.1.2 cross-compiler) integer promotion problem

Tags: c++, c, gcc, char, powerpc

This is the test code.

```
char ch = 0xff;
int i = ch;
printf("%d\n", i);
```

In i386 gcc-4.4.5, **the output is -1**.
But in powerpc-e300c3-linux-gnu-gcc-4.1.2(MPC8315 cross-compiler), **the output is 255**.

What is wrong?
Why gcc-4.1.2 output is 255?

Thanks for your answer...

Comment: I've run into this problem as well.  `char` is "usually" signed, but on PowerPC Linux, it's unsigned.  When I discovered this, I was coding on PowerPC, and had this code: `unsigned char charflag[256]; ... charflag[c] & CF_WHITE`.  The problem is, when `c` is a char of the non-ASCII variety, it results in negative indexes when `char` is signed.  The fix was to say `charflag[(unsigned char)c]`, as that prevents the spurious sign extension.

Comment: Assigning the value of 255 to a char is not a good idea anyhow: "Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised." You can only assume that you can store values up to 127 in a plain `char`. As a simple rule, never use plain `char` for arithmetic.

Answer (score 9):

It is implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned.

Apparently it is signed on your x86 compiler and unsigned on your PowerPC compiler.

For portability, use `unsigned char` or `signed char` wherever you care about the signedness.

Comment: GCC has the `-fsigned-char` flag that forces `char` to be signed on all platforms.  That's a nice quick-fix for porting code, but you should still get into the habit of seeing that `char`'s signedness is implementation-defined.

Comment: Or better yet, if one really cares about the size of variables, it is better to state it explicitly. Use the stdint.h header (in C99 and above) - it has int8_t and uint8_t. Although I really don't like the '_t's.

Comment: @Hex, `char` is always 1 byte, and it's 8 bits on the vast majority of modern systems.  Also, you can make typedefs without the `_t`.

Comment: POSIX requires `char` to be 8 bits, and `uint8_t` *cannot exist* on a platform (due to conflicting restraints imposed by the standard) if `char` is not 8 bits.